# trying to connect curl with express js

Tags: php, node.js, express, curl

Hello I am trying to connect from my site with curl (php) to a rest api (node js-express-js) i have made. Everythink seems to work fine except the answer from curl is empty

server from node-js:

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());




var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();  

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});


app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on ' + port);
```

On my site i am trying to retrieve the json by using curl:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "xxx:8080/api/"); // i removed the ip from my server for safety reasons

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
print "output=";
print_r($ouput);
    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Note: sending a get request above from postman i receive the answer i want. I don't know what is wrong. Thx in advance.

Also, curl is a blocking function.. right?

Both "servers" are on the same server. I don't know if is an error like cross-server-origin of javascript

Comment: Have you tried answering with simple string?

Comment: @Lazyexpert yep I tried the "res.send('test')" but the result is still the same... Nothing

Comment: You might check for a curl error after `curl_exec()`: `if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); }`. If that doesn't output anything, try checking the status code with `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`

Comment: @mscdex I get the message operation completed withought any error. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What was the status code?

Comment: @mscdex the status from http_code was 200  meaning everything was fine. Seems that the problem is at the way i send the data from node-js though accessing the url directly or by postman works fine

Comment: Well the only other possibility is that you've removed other code which contains a middleware or route handler that prematurely responds to the request, since the code you currently show should work fine.

Comment: @mscdex there is no other middleware that i use. Should I?

Comment: Not unless you need them. Out of curiosity, did you try removing the trailing '/' from the URL in your PHP code?

Comment: @JmRag I know this is very old but was wondering if you could make that work and remember how?

Answer (score 0):

reason why you don't get response via php - wrong var name in print_r func

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "xxx:8080/api/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
print "output=";

print_r($output); // missed t in output

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers** and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers (if there are any). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29924018)

Comment: This answer is pointing out a typo.

Comment: Do not post answers to problems caused by typo type issues, they should be called out in comments and flagged, as there is a specific close flag **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. These questions are typically downvoted, closed and deleted, as they are of no benefit to the community.